# Rstudio unable to install 'psimetrica-R' package from Github

Tags: r, github, devtools, install.packages

I am unable to install a package on Github using Rstudio (version 4.0.4). The package is here: https://github.com/stmueller/psimetrica-R

I've tried to install directly from console with the following:

```
install.packages("psimetrica-R", repos = "https://github.com/stmueller/psimetrica-R.git")
```

which causes Rstudio to print the following error:

> Warning in install.packages :   unable to access index for repository
> https://github.com/stmueller/psimetrica-R.git/src/contrib:   cannot
> open URL
> 'https://github.com/stmueller/psimetrica-R.git/src/contrib/PACKAGES'
> Warning in install.packages :   package ‘psimetrica-R’ is not
> available for this version of R
>
> A version of this package for your version of R might be available
> elsewhere, see the ideas at
> https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-patched/R-admin.html#Installing-packages
> Warning in install.packages :   unable to access index for repository
> https://github.com/stmueller/psimetrica-R.git/bin/windows/contrib/4.0:
> cannot open URL
> 'https://github.com/stmueller/psimetrica-R.git/bin/windows/contrib/4.0/PACKAGES'

I also tried:

```
devtools::install_github("stmueller/psimetrica-R")
```

which causes:

> Error: Failed to install 'unknown package' from GitHub:   HTTP error
> 404.   Not Found
>
> Did you spell the repo owner (`stmueller`) and repo name
> (`psimetrica-R`) correctly?
> If spelling is correct, check that you have the required permissions to access the repo.

I've also tried downloading the ZIP file from the repo page and installing with:

```
install.packages("C:/Users/lyamm/Downloads/psimetrica-R-master.zip", repos = NULL, type = "win.binary")
```

which causes...

> Installing package into ‘C:/Users/lyamm/Documents/R/win-library/4.0’
> (as ‘lib’ is unspecified) Warning in install.packages :   cannot open
> compressed file 'psimetrica-R-master/DESCRIPTION', probable reason 'No
> such file or directory' Error in install.packages : cannot open the
> connection

Am I doing something wrong? Or is there a problem with / missing files in the package itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A github *source* repository is not an R package repository like CRAN -- so you cannot use `install.packages()`.

Instead, use `remotes::install_gihub()` as in

```
if (!requireNamespace("remotes", quietly=TRUE)) install.packages("remotes")
remotes::install_github("stmueller/psimetrica-R")
```

This will install `remotes` if needed, and use it to install the desired package.

Or, at least, that would work in principle *if* `psimetrica-R` was a regular R source package. Here it fails *because of its layout*:

```
> remotes::install_github("stmueller/psimetrica-R")
Error: Failed to install 'unknown package' from GitHub:
  cannot open URL 'https://api.github.com/repos/stmueller/psimetrica-R/contents/DESCRIPTION?ref=HEAD'
>
```

So you could fork the repo and make it proper package first. At least open source lets you do that.

Comment: Thanks, Dirk! I don't really have any experience publishing R packages, so could you point me towards a resource outlining the requirements (i.e., the changes I would have to make in order to make it a proper package)?

Comment: At a minimum, files `DESCRIPTION` and `NAMESPACE`.  See [Writing R Extensions](https://rstudio.github.io/r-manuals/r-exts/) and other resources on packages, or maybe reach out to some friends or colleagues who may be able to give you a hand.

Comment: Fair enough, thanks for the help!